# How to change the state of a CheckBox from true to false when I click in a different Check box

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio in VB, I have 3 check boxes, one is set by default to be True, but when I select on of the other checkbox and change it to True, I want to set all the other Checkboxes to False I have tried some fairly simple code but it doesn't work - can someone help me? I am newish to code...!
I have tried

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
ChecBox2.checked= False
CheckBox3.checked = False
End If
```

Comment: _"I have tried some fairly simple code but it doesn't work"_ Include it in the question so that it becomes easier to point out any mistake.

Comment: As well as the code - you say `VB` and tag `VBA`?  I'm guessing VB as you're using Visual Studio rather than an MS Office program?

Comment: Then, please use `Visual Studio` tag. This is  not a VBA question... If you will share the code, at least, we will maybe help you, even without that tag. Are you using a special add-in allowing to use VBA?

Comment: Change checkbox to radiobutton and give them a group name.

Comment: How do I group Radio buttons to work like that?